# Why am I getting the EPOLLHUP event on a brand new socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, epoll

I have some code that when run on a virtual machine is misbehaving for some reason.

The order of initialization is:

```
s_listen = socket(...)
bind(s_listen, ...)
epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, s_listen, ...)
listen(s_listen, SOMAXCONN)
```

There is an event loop/thread running and processing events on the epoll file descriptor before bind is even called.

That event loop gets an EPOLLHUP before the call to listen() on the newly created s_listen socket.

So my question is, why am I getting the EPOLLHUP event on a brand new socket?

The error goes away when I put the epoll_ctl after call to listen(), however will that cause some potential connection events to be missed should they come in before the socket is added to epoll?

Comment: It's been a while since I used poll and friends, but I don't remember ever adding an fd to a poll set before it was properly set up (i.e., after calling `accept`, `connect` or `listen`). Are you sure that adding a non-initialized socket to an epoll set is valid?

Comment: Absolutely valid.  You can add any valid socket even before connect/bind/accept.

Comment: [This code](http://pastebin.com/jyn2K3XX) prints: "Events: err=0, hup=16". So are you really really sure it's valid? (Well, I guess getting POLLHUP is valid, but you get what I meant.)

Comment: That link takes me to "unknown pastbin id".  Anyway, changing the order of things and filtering the event properly solved it.

Comment: I had set the expiration to 1 day; I re-uploaded it [here](http://pastebin.com/dnK0iaLY) with 1 month expiration now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As my example in the comments shows, it seems you can't poll the socket before it's properly initialized, unless you want to handle `EPOLLHUP`.

As for the question, no, you won't miss any events. Calling `listen()` then `epoll()` is the same you'd have to do otherwise (`listen()` + blocking `accept()`); actual incoming connections between those calls are handled by the kernel and stay waiting until your code handles them.

Comment: No that is incorrect.  Your socket is alive as soon as a call to  socket() has completed.  i.e. it is a properly initialized socket as far as TCP/IP is concerned.  I have other code that creates it non-blocking, adds it to epoll and calls connect.  When epoll_wait returns a writeable event I know it's connected.  In this code, I don't see the HUP event.

Comment: See my other comment with the pastebin code. An uninitialized (i.e. before connect / listen) socket always seems to cause EPOLLHUP (at least when in blocking mode).